# Issues compiling passenger for apache2 on CentOS

Tags: installation, centos, apache-http-server, ruby, passenger

I am trying to install openproject on a CentOS 6.5 (Release 3 from OVH) following [this tutorial](https://www.openproject.org/projects/openproject/wiki/Installation_on_Centos_65_x64_with_Apache_and_PostgreSQL_93) but with mysql in place of postgresql.

I'm nearly done but I can't seem to compile passenger for apache :

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Here is the result :

---

*Welcome to the Phusion Passenger Apache 2 module installer, v4.0.40.*

This installer will guide you through the entire installation process. It
shouldn't take more than 3 minutes in total.

Here's what you can expect from the installation process:

1. The Apache 2 module will be installed for you.
2. You'll learn how to configure Apache.
3. You'll learn how to deploy a Ruby on Rails application.

Don't worry if anything goes wrong. This installer will advise you on how to
solve any problems.

Press Enter to continue, or Ctrl-C to abort.

Which languages are you interested in?

Use  to select.
If the menu doesn't display correctly, press '!'

(*)  Ruby
   ( )  Python
   ( )  Node.js
   ( )  Meteor

Checking for required software...

- Checking for C compiler...
    Found: yes
    Location: /usr/bin/cc
- Checking for C++ compiler...
    Found: yes
    Location: /usr/bin/c++
- Checking for Curl development headers with SSL support...
    Found: yes
    curl-config location: /usr/bin/curl-config
    Header location: /usr/include/curl/curl.h
    Version: libcurl 7.19.7
    Usable: yes
    Supports SSL: yes
- Checking for OpenSSL development headers...
    Found: yes
    Location: /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h
- Checking for Zlib development headers...
    Found: yes
    Location: /usr/include/zlib.h
- Checking for Apache 2...
    Found: yes
    Location of httpd: /usr/sbin/httpd
    Apache version: 2.2.15
- Checking for Apache 2 development headers...
    Found: no
- Checking for Rake (associated with /home/openproject/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/wrappers/ruby)...
    Found: yes
    Location: /home/openproject/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/wrappers/rake
- Checking for OpenSSL support for Ruby...
    Found: yes
- Checking for RubyGems...
    Found: yes
- Checking for Ruby development headers...
    Found: yes
    Location: /home/openproject/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby.h
- Checking for rack...
    Found: yes
- Checking for Apache Portable Runtime (APR) development headers...
    Found: no
- Checking for Apache Portable Runtime Utility (APU) development headers...
    Found: no

Some required software is not installed.
But don't worry, this installer will tell you how to install them.
Press Enter to continue, or Ctrl-C to abort.

Installation instructions for required software

- To install Apache 2 development headers:
  Please install it with yum install httpd-devel
- To install Apache Portable Runtime (APR) development headers:
  Please install it with yum install apr-devel
- To install Apache Portable Runtime Utility (APU) development headers:
  Please install it with yum install apr-util-devel

If the aforementioned instructions didn't solve your problem, then please take
a look at the Users Guide:

/home/openproject/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.40/doc/Users guide Apache.html
  http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html

---

So it seems that apr-devel, apr-util-devel and httpd-devel are missing. So I'm trying to install them :

```
yum install apr-devel apr-util-devel httpd-devel
```

But the result is very surprising :

---

*Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities*

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

epel/metalink

- base: mirror.ovh.net
- epel: mirrors.coreix.net
- extras: mirror.ovh.net
- rpmforge: www.mirrorservice.org
- updates: mirror.ovh.net

LocalRepo

rpmforge

1458 packages excluded due to repository priority protections

Setting up Install Process

Package apr-devel-1.3.9-5.el6_2.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Package apr-util-devel-1.3.9-3.el6_0.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Resolving Dependencies

--> Running transaction check

---> Package httpd-devel.x86_64 0:2.2.15-29.el6.centos will be installed

--> Processing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.15-29.el6.centos for package: httpd-devel-2.2.15-29.el6.centos.x86_64

--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Error: Package: httpd-devel-2.2.15-29.el6.centos.x86_64 (base)

Requires: httpd = 2.2.15-29.el6.centos

Installed: httpd-2.2.15-29.1.el6.x86_64 (@LocalRepo)

httpd = 2.2.15-29.1.el6

Available: httpd-2.2.15-29.el6.centos.x86_64 (base)

httpd = 2.2.15-29.el6.centos

You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

---

I'm interpreting this as the result of having OVH modify a lot of the files for their ow release thus preventing any kind of update. It is to be noted that I had to remove httpd* from the excludes in order to do anything.

2 Questions :

- What can I do about the httpd-devel package ?
- Why doesn't passenger recognize the apr packages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue until i found out that one of the only repo for CentOs indexing httpd-devel was the Virtualmin repo. Just install Virtualmin :

```
rpm -ivh http://software.virtualmin.com/gpl/centos/6/x86_64/virtualmin-release-latest.noarch.rpm
```

Then yum install httpd-devel will work fine !